# Conversion tool .spark to cshtml options

Tags: model-view-controller

I am looking for a good conversion tool for .spark files to cshtml in a .net mvc project. Can anyone let me know any recommendations. An example of spark file is below:

```
<use master="Page"/>
<viewdata profiles="List<Profile>"/>

<side />

<div class="mainArea">
    <ul>
        <li each="Profile profile in profiles" style="color:green;?${profile.Location!=null}">

            <b>${profile.Name}</b>
            <br/><span style="color:orange;">${profile.Location.Country.Name} / ${profile.Location.Name}</span>
            <br/><span if="profile.Location!=null" style="color:green;">${profile.Location.Country} / ${profile.Location.Name}}</span>


        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```